# $L^1$ convergence in something like law of large numbers - what assumptions do we need?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stationary-processes

I'm trying to prove that for a stationary and ergodic sequence of martingale differences $X_i$ such that $E X_i = 0$ and $E X_i^2 = \sigma^2 < \infty$ the convergence of $\frac 1n (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)^2$ to $\sigma^2$ is in fact $L_1$ convergence.

I know I have a pointwise convergence of mean of that expression which follows easily from the strong law of large numbers and the fact that those variables are martingale differences. I know it would be true for $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$ because then the uniform integrability would be trivial, but is there any way to prove it for sequence including mixed terms, ie $X_i X_j$? I know I need uniform integrability to obtain that but is it already implied by the assumptions (i.e.  stationarity and ergodicity)? If so, what are the tools one can use to prove it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Davide pinging you since you wrote the tag-wiki. Are you intending the (stationary-processes) to be used for only random processes? The way that the tag-wiki is written can also be applicable to deterministic discrete dynamical systems; I think it would be helpful to specify random processes if that is the case.

Comment: Actually, I think it could be a good idea to deal with deterministic discrete dynamical systems. I will edit the tag-wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a approach: use a truncation argument and the fourth moments inequality 
$$E\left(\sum_{j=1}^nD_j\right)^4\leqslant 6 n^2c^4,$$
where $\{D_j\}$ is a sequence of martingales differences such that $|D_j|\leqslant c$ almost surely (for each $j$).

Indeed, let $(X_i,\mathcal F_i)$ be a stationary and ergodic sequence of martingale differences. For a fixed $c$, define $X_i':=X_i\chi_{\{|X_i|\leqslant c\}}-\mathbb E[X_i\chi_{\{|X_i|\leqslant c\}}\mid \mathcal F_{i-1}]$ and $X''_i:=X_i\chi_{\{|X_i|\gt c\}}-\mathbb E[X_i\chi_{\{|X_i|\gt c\}}\mid \mathcal F_{i-1}]$. Then $X_i=X'_i+X''_i$. Denoting $S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=S'_n+S''_n$, we have 
$$\mathbb E[|S_n|^2\chi_{|S_n|\gt 4R}]\leqslant \mathbb E[|S_n'|^2\chi_{\{|S_n'|\gt R\}}]+\mathbb E[|S_n''|^2\chi_{\{|S_n''|\gt R\}}].$$

We have for each positive $R$ that 
$$\mathbb E[|S_n''|^2\chi_{\{|S_n''|\gt R\}}]\leqslant n\mathbb E[|X_1|^2\chi_{\{|X_1|\gt c\}}]$$
and 
$$E[|S_n'|^2\chi_{\{|S_n'|\gt R\}}]\leqslant (\mathbb E[S_n'^4])^{1/2}(\mu\{|S_n'|\gt R\})^{1/2}\leqslant 6^{1/2}c^2n^{3/2}\frac c{R}.$$
This gives 
$$E[|S_n'|^2/n\chi_{\{|S_n'|\gt \sqrt nR\}}]\leqslant \frac Knc^3n^{3/2}\frac 1{\sqrt nR}=\frac{Kc^3}R,$$
where $K$ is independent of $n$, $r$ and $c$.

Plugging these estimates, we get 
$$\mathbb E[|S_n|^2/n\chi_{|S_n|\gt 4\sqrt nR}]\leqslant K(\mathbb E[|X_1|^2\chi_{\{|X_1|\gt c\}}] +\frac{c^3}R).$$

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. I don't see how a truncation argument would work here. If the martingale differences were bounded there wouldn't be a problem, but if I artificially truncate them then first they need not be martingale differences (not so much of a problem), but second the remainders $X_i \mathbb{1} _{ \{|X_i| > c \} } $ will have to be included inside the squared sum and I don't see how to push it forward. Btw I also posted a simpler version of this problem - where $X_i$ are iid random variables, I'd be greatful if you looked into it if you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You can take this term minus its condition expectation to a good $\sigma$-algebra in order to make it a martingale difference term.

Comment: I've edited, hoping it's clearer now.